# Installed ubuntu and trying to install motherboard drivers from from a usb, but the flash drive isn't showing up in "disks."

Tags: drivers, usb

What should I do? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. This is the first time I am using Ubuntu on my system.

Side question:
In the about this computer, it's displaying the wrong graphics card. Is that because I haven't installed the drivers yet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 Root Hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 Root Hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 Root Hub
Bus 008 Device 004: ID 1048:07d3 Targus Group International
Bus 008 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Reciever
Bus 008 Device 005: ID 05ac:0220 Apple, Inc. Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Are you able to connect any other USB device other than the mentioned?

Comment: Yes, my mouse and keyboard work fine. However, they only work in the 3.0 slots, and I don't have any other devices to test in the 2.0 ones.

Comment: Would you please edit your question and give us the output of `lsusb` while your USB devices are still connected to your system?

Comment: hahaha I updated it, I had to type each line by hand. As it is, my motherboard drivers haven't been installed, and as such, I can't connect to my wifi. I'm using my laptop to make this thread.

Comment: apologies for the many edits. Trying to make this a painless process for all involved.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your USB device in USB 3.0 slot?

Comment: Alright, this is really strange. The usb shows up when in the 3.0 slot, great! However, the mouse ONLY works when the keyboard is plugged in too. The keyboard does not function when it's in the 2.0 slot, same for the mouse. But I know the 2.0 slots work, because my keyboard was working fine plugged in there, when I was messing with the BIOS. Very confused. Also, if you can initiate a chat, that would be good, because I cannot. Too little rep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem (connecting USB devices to the system via USB 2.0 ports) but you can give it a try.

Install `usbmount` on your system. You can either install it from the `Ubuntu Software Center` ;

[image: installing <code>usbmount</code> from Software Center]

Or by using `Synaptic Package Manager`;

[image: installing <code>usbmount</code> from Synaptic Package Manager]

As it can be seen in the description, `usbmount` automatically moounts USB mass storage devices. Once it has been installed, connect your USB device and see if it shows up.

I hope this would help in resolving your problem.